# embedded signing in docusign without templates

Tags: php, docusignapi

i am using the rest api (in php) for docusign.

There are 3 types of users, User A , User B and the administrator.

Now user A uploads a document and sends it to user B who will sign it using docusign. But user A needs to have the option to tag and send the document. As far i know, the only way to do this is to use embedded signing. (http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSending).
But embedded sending uses templates .

So my question is

1. How can i use embedded signing **without** using templates?
2. I am storing the api credentials in the admin side and using this credentials to create a url to redirect user A to embedded sending. But i dont want user A to have admin access in docusign.
3. After sending the document to User B how would  i redirect user A back to my appication?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to #1:  Using embedded sending or embedded signing without templates is easy, just use the request body for [requesting a signature on a document api call](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument) instead of through a template.

For #2: It doesn't matter if an admin creates the embedded signing url, the recipient who receives it will not have admin access or any other type of access they're not supposed to have when opening the envelope.

For #3:  Take a look at the [Embedded Sending API Walkthrough](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSending), in the example they set a `returnUrl` which the user is redirected to once the sending is complete.  Look at the third step of the walkthrough, it sets the request body to this (PHP version):

```
$data = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter");
```

Comment: Is it possible to prevent User A from adding recipients or otherwise modifying the envelope information?

Comment: I don't believe so - if User A has enough permissions to create the envelope to begin with, then they should be able to add recipients and modify envelope info.  How is User A creating the envelope in your case?

Comment: I'm creating it and I want to control who it gets sent to for embedded signing.